# Will official 'Mango' release allow sideloading of apps on WP7 devices?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any news whether the official Mango release will allow sideloading of apps? I mean ability to deploy apps without going through the MarketPlace? I would like to see the ability to deploy my own apps on my own device without using third party services and paying extra fees. I don't plan to publish apps publicly. (I tried ChevronWP7 and it couldn't work as intended. Probably obsoleted by MS.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. According to the TechDay event, there will be two channels for side-loading apps. One channel is for Beta apps - specifically for side-loading apps at the Beta stage of development, and the other channel is for private apps which are ready for release.

So the WP7 app marketplace will have 3 channels when Mango is released:

1. Beta
2. Private
3. Public

Comment: So are you saying that in order to publish a private app, you will still have to submit it to the marketplace?  If so, this would be a non-starter for enterprises that want to publish internal apps with proprietary code or trade secrets built into them.